# Tensorflow Inception v3 retraining - attach text/labels to individual images

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am using the inception v3 model to retrain my own dataset. I have few folder which represent the classes which contain images for each class. What i would like to do is to 'attach' some text ids to these images so when they are retrained and used to run classification/similarity-detection those ids are retrieved too. (basically its image similarity detection)

For instance, Image X is of class 'Teachers' and it belongs to John. When i retrain the model, and run a classification on the new model, i would like to get the Teachers class, but in addition to this i would like to know who is teacher (John).

Any ideas how to go for it?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 main options - multiply your classes, multi-label learning or training several models.

The first option is the most straight forward - instead of having  teachers who belong to John and teachers who belong to Jane you can have teachers whose class is Teachers_John and class whose class is Teachers_John and learn to classify to those categories as you would learn any other set of categories, or use something like hierarchical softmax.

The second option is to have a set of categories that includes Teachers as well as John and Jane - now your target is not to correctly predict the one most accurate class (Teachers) but several (Teachers and John).

Your last option is to create a hierarchy of models where the first learns to differentiate between John and Jane and others to classify the inner classes for each of them.